# Using new xmlns.jcp.org namespace on composites causes java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent

Tags: jsf, facelets, xml-namespaces, composite-component, jsf-2.2

I am reading The Java EE 7 Tutorial from http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-facelets005.htm#GIQZR

After I typed the example code in the chapter 8.5 Composite Components in my IDE and run the example on GlassFish4.0, I got an error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1078)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Cache.get(Cache.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.getComponentMetadata(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:237)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:951)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.createComponent(ApplicationWrapper.java:648)
```

Then I check the older version of this tutorial, I found a difference.

In the Java EE 7 version the email.xhtml code is like following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:composite="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <title>This content will not be displayed</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="value" required="false"/>
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <h:outputLabel value="Email id: "></h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}"></h:inputText>
    </composite:implementation>
</h:body>
</html>
```

But in the Java EE 6 version

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <title>This content will not be displayed</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="value" required="false"/>
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <h:outputLabel value="Email id: "></h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}"></h:inputText>
    </composite:implementation>
</h:body>
</html>
```

After I changed the code to Java EE 6 version, the error is gone. The difference is the namespace. I don't know whether this is an issue of this tutorial. Is there any knows?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way how the new `xmlns.jcp.org` XML namespaces are been handled is broken in the first Mojarra releases 2.2.0 and 2.2.1. It has been fixed in [Mojarra 2.2.2](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2900) (note: ticket in the link describes different problem symptom, but under the covers, it's essentially the same cause). It's recommended to upgrade to at least Mojarra 2.2.2 (always pick the newest available, if possible). GlassFish 4.0 has 2.2.0 bundled. You can get the JAR from [javaserverfaces.java.net](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/). All you need to do is to replace `javax.faces.jar` file in GlassFish's `/modules` folder with the newer version.

The Java EE 7 tutorial itself is fine. It was just the implementation which was broken. This kind of trouble is by the way not unusual with the very first major GlassFish release (all hastle to get it ready on time). I recommend to wait with Java EE 7 until GlassFish 4.0.1 or 4.1 has been brought out to avoid future surprises. Note that other vendors like Apache Tomcat and JBoss AS take their time to release a Java EE 7 container; they don't have a production ready version yet.

Comment: I have downloaded jar Mojarra 2.2.2 from the link and put it into     /modules. But I still have the same issue. I think I should wait for GlassFish 4.1. Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your problem on an unmodified GF4 setup. Your use case started to work for me after I upgraded it with Mojarra 2.2.2. Did you clean up the GF4 work/cache/deploy folders? How are you managing the server? Standalone or via an IDE? Note that I generally don't post answers if I haven't confirmed/experienced the very problem myself as well.

Comment: Sorry for the first comments. I forget to rename the jar file to let GlassFish load it first. It works now. Thanks