# using JSF 2 tags in JSP file

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-2

Is it possible to use JSF 2 tags from a JSP file

for example

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:event listener="#{user.isAdmin}" type="preRenderView" />
</f:metadata>
```

or any other facelet tags from a JSF file?

Comment: Why would you use jsf2 with jsp? And simple answer: TRY!

Comment: migrating an old project from JSF 1.1 that using JSP as a view to JSF 2.0, I already tried and it doesn't work and need a clear answer from someone who used it before.

Comment: Well... maybe it just does not work... And please learn a little searching...  Doing this: https://www.google.nl/search?q=does+a+metadata+tag+work+in+a+jsp+file+jsf resulted in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491157/metadata-tag-not-working-in-jsf

Comment: I already went through all these questions and they didn't answer my question. using facelets instead of JSPs is not an option in our case, also after investigation I could use facelet tags -yes its behavior is not as expected- but it proves that the answer in your attached question is wrong so, you need to consider that question as not duplicate.

Comment: It is a perfect duplicate... I read the answer in the duplicate... Quote: _"Some tags, namely the ones used by you like <f:metadata> and <f:viewParam> are not available in JSPs (see sections 10.4.1.3 and 2.5.5 of JSF 2.2 specification (JSR-344) respectively)."_