# viewAction and ViewParam not working with the new namespace

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish, netbeans-8

I'm working with Netbeans 8.0 and Glassfish 4. I'm using this piece of code in a JSF page:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam id="id" name="id" value="#{profileMB.idProfile}"  />
    <f:viewAction action="#{profileMB.loadProfile()}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

It's working When I declare with the old namespace:

```
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
```

but it's not working with the new one:

```
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Are these pertaining to your taglib?

Comment: I've found the problem, it's a bug from Mojarra ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the answer...
It's a bug in the version of Mojarra used in Glassfish 4

[f:viewParam doesn't pass required parameter when new xmlns.jcp.org namespace is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517384/fviewparam-doesnt-pass-required-parameter-when-new-xmlns-jcp-org-namespace-is)