# XML Error while building JSF project

Tags: jsf, netbeans, jsf-2.2

I generated Entity Classes from database then I generated JSF pages from them but when I click on any show table this message displays 3 times:
Warning this page calls for XML namespaces http://xlmns.jsp.org/jsffacelets declared with prefix ui but no taglibrary exists for that namespace

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using new xmlns.jcp.org namespace on composites causes java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436511/using-new-xmlns-jcp-org-namespace-on-composites-causes-java-lang-nullpointerexce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For UI tags you need to use following tag library.

```
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets
```

Please check following link,

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/

Comment: This is true for JSF 2.x until latest JSF 2.1 distribution. Since JSF 2.2, there are new namespaces. This is the only official resource I can give regarding this: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/overview-summary.html

Comment: Sorry. I did not know that.

Comment: I didn't know either until I read the possible duplicate question I proposed. BalusC's answer explains this in details.