# Passing parameter between pages

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, viewparams

I'm unable to pass a simple parameter from one Facelet to another, and set a bean property...here's my code:

The calling page, **main.xhtml** (only relevant code):

```
<h:link outcome="index" value="disconnect" >
     <f:param name="logout" value="true" />
</h:link>
```

The final page, **index.xhtml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="logout" value="#{indexBean.logout}"/>
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{indexBean.redirect}" />
    </f:metadata>
</html>
```

And the **IndexBean** (only relevant code):

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class IndexBean {

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    private boolean logout;

    public IndexBean() {this.logout = false;}

    public void setLogout(boolean logout) {
            logger.log(Level.DEBUG, "logout changed");
            this.logout = logout;
    }

    public boolean isLogout() {return logout;}

    public void redirect() throws IOException {
        if(logout) {
            //Never get in here
        } else {
            //Always here
        }

    }
}
```

I'm getting the URL parameter right on the link (http://localhost/index.xhtml?logout=true), but the `setLogout` method is never called.

I've even tried to change the `logout` type to String, change getter and setter properly and see what happens, but the setter is never called...

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? Anything in server logs? Any messages when you add `<h:messages>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using new xmlns.jcp.org namespace on composites causes java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436511/using-new-xmlns-jcp-org-namespace-on-composites-causes-java-lang-nullpointerexce)